# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated error in java

Tags: http-post, httpclient

I' getting following error when I try to run the application in the server. Some of APIs working in the server without an issue and only one API giving following error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
```

This is the code I'm trying to access the API.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://mife.smobile.lk/apicall/dialogloanprepaid/v1.0/auto");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"msisdn\":\"" + mobile
                + "\",\"channel\":\"IVR\"}");

        new StringEntity(json.toString());
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        post.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("status code is :" + status);
        resCode = Integer.toString(status);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String response1 = readAll(rd);
        System.out.println(response1);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response1);
        resCode = obj.getString("resCode");
        resDesc = obj.getString("resDesc");
```

Is there anything can be done from the code level in order to sort out the issue. Please help.